# If one field empty, assign second to variable

Tags: php, mysql, database, post, submit

I'm stuck with a very simple thing. I have two fields (maybe will be 3 later) on one page. Each field opens up by clicking radio button (other fields hide). I want to send field value to database, but i want all values to re-write one another, depending on what field is chosen. I have this code:

```
       $get_amount_field = Tools::getValue('amount');
        $get_value = Tools::getValue('formula');

        if (isset($get_value)) {
         $name_formatted = str_replace(' 2', '', $get_name);
         $amount="UPDATE `pr_manufacturer` SET amount = '$get_value' WHERE name = '$name_formatted' ";
         $get_amount = Db::getInstance()->execute($amount);
        }
        elseif (isset($get_amount_field)) {
         $name_formatted = str_replace(' 2', '', $get_name);
         $amount="UPDATE `pr_manufacturer` SET amount = '$get_amount_field' WHERE name = '$name_formatted' ";
         $get_amount = Db::getInstance()->execute($amount);
        }
```

but it saves only `$get_value` value. If, for example, `$get_value` value is none, and `$get_amount_field` is **25** - after first submit button click database returns old `$get_value` value, and after second submit with same value of `$get_amount_field` - database column is just empty. What am I doing wrong perhaps?

Comment: In your usage here, `$get_value` is ALWAYS going to be set. Because you set it right above the `if isset` block. Maybe what you are looking for is `!empty` ?

Comment: BTW: You have some dangerous sql injection risk here. Please look into using prepared statements.

Comment: **WARNING**: Whenever possible use **prepared statements with placeholder values** to avoid injecting arbitrary data in your queries and creating [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.

Comment: : "It looks like you're writing your own ORM. Have you considered using one that's already written, tested, and widely supported like [RedBeanPHP](https://redbeanphp.com/), [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/),  or
[Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent)?" In an ORM **this is a solved problem**, you don't need to painfully reinvent this functionality.